# If $H$ and $Z$ are closed subgroups generating $G$, is $H \times Z \rightarrow G$ an open map?

Tags: gn.general-topology, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a Hausdorff topological group with center $Z$ and closed subgroup $H$.  Suppose that $H.Z = G$.  Is the product map

$$H \times Z \rightarrow G$$

necessarily an open map?  That is, can we identify with $G$ as a quotient group of $H \times Z$?

Comment: If $G$ is second-countable and locally compact (so $H \times Z$ is too) then this is affirmative since for any transitive continuous action of a second-countable group $\mathscr{G}$ (e.g., $H \times Z$) on a locally compact Hausdorff space $X$ (e.g., left multiplication on $G$ through the surjective homomorphism) the continuous bijective orbit map $\mathscr{G}/{\rm{Stab}}_{\mathscr{G}}(x) \to X$ for $x \in X$ is a homeomorphism.  The role of second-countability is to apply the Baire category theorem. See section 5 in Ch. IX of Bourbaki's *General Topology* for a proof in a wider context.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly the kind of result I was hoping for

Comment: I meant to require $\mathscr{G}$ to also be locally compact and Hausdorff (not just second-countable) in the general assertion of my previous comment.

Comment: The same is true if $G$ is Polish, more generally, Lindelof and Cech-complete.

Comment: Btw the results mentioned by nfdc and Taras are fine for $Z$ central, not with the artificial assumption that the center is reduced to $Z$ (and probably $Z$ normal is enough; I'm only sure in the locally compact 2nd countable case). An easy counterexample, with non-Polish separable metrizable groups (and when one assume $Z$ central) is when $H,Z$ are two mutually irrational cyclic subgroups of the reals and $G$ is their sum, with the induced topology. With $Z$ equal to the center we can produce more complicated examples as other dense countable subgroups of Lie groups.